# Can collector auto populate related feature ID field?

Tags: relationship-class, arcgis-collector

I have staff conducting hydrants inspections using ESRI ArcGIS collector. The hydrants have a unique ID. If I make a relationship class between hydrants and hydrant inspections, does Collector know to auto populate the hydrant inspection facility id with the hydrants unique ID?

The hydrant inspection layer is a feature class, not a table.

I know collector is able to auto populate related tables; however, what about related feature classes.

Comment: im fairly sure that yes collector will auto populate the hydrants ID when you edit the related featureclass.

Comment: I know it's nearly a year later - but did you figure out if this was possible to do?

Comment: @MKF Yes, it works the same for feature class.